# What was this menu application in DOS?

Tags: ms-dos, identify-this-software

My father's computer in the early 90s (probably 1991, or at the latest 1992) had a piece of software that acted as an application launcher. I think it was simply called "menu".

Its graphics were simple text-based ones, with all borders drawn as characters such as full block (similarly to classic DOS software like QBasic and Lotus 1-2-3).

The application simply displayed a 3x3 grid of white rectangles, and each had the name of a program in it. Pressing a function key (F1-F9) would launch the corresponding software, and page up/down switched "pages" (groups of 9 applications).

Other keys were used to edit which application corresponded to each rectangle, probably with the path to an executable and a display name.

Once an application was launched an exited, it would simply drop back to a command line. I think the command to make the menu appear again was simply `menu`. This was definitely not run on Windows, simply MS-DOS.

I've tried a few searches but I couldn't find any reference to such a launcher. Given the simplicity, I think it's entirely possible that a programmer friend of my father had made it for us, but I'd like to be sure.

This is a mockup of how I remember it looking (the full block characters aren't full blocks in this website's font):

```
█████████████████████████████████████████████████
█┌──────1──────┐█┌──────2──────┐█┌──────3──────┐█
█│             │█│             │█│             │█
█│    ProgA    │█│    ProgB    │█│    ProgC    │█
█│             │█│             │█│             │█
█└─────────────┘█└─────────────┘█└─────────────┘█
█████████████████████████████████████████████████
█┌──────4──────┐█┌──────5──────┐█┌──────6──────┐█
█│             │█│             │█│             │█
█│    ProgD    │█│    ProgE    │█│    ProgF    │█
█│             │█│             │█│             │█
█└─────────────┘█└─────────────┘█└─────────────┘█
█████████████████████████████████████████████████
█┌──────7──────┐█┌──────8──────┐█┌──────9──────┐█
█│             │█│             │█│             │█
█│    ProgG    │█│    ProgH    │█│    ProgI    │█
█│             │█│             │█│             │█
█└─────────────┘█└─────────────┘█└─────────────┘█
█████████████████████████████████████████████████
 PgUp/Dn: Change page      F1-9: Select
```

Comment: Even with your good description, without more information, this will be hopeless. There have been gazillions of Menu applications. From simple batch files, written by users or their software suppliers (which your description fits quite well) asking for "Press F for Filing" all the way to replacement shells. Many PC-Manufacturers even added similar systems to their OEM-DOS (Like Siemens did for the PC-D starting with DOS 2). That stuff was plenty.

Comment: The closest thing I've personally seen to this was At Ease on the Macintosh, but that's undoubtedly the wrong answer. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/At_Ease

Comment: This looks very similar to an application I used in 1995 called Buttons for DOS

Comment: <http://www.retroarchive.org/garbo/pc/menu/index.html> hosts a number of menu programs, maybe you can find it among those.

Comment: IIRC there was some kind of "tiled" menu system common on IBM PS/1 type machines?

Comment: I can't remember the name of the suite for generating these but I remember seeing it at the tills in Disneyland Florida in the early 90s.  The squares could merge to form panels for receipts and the menus would overwrite each other with new buttons.  They used a strain gauge at the bottom of a CRT to work out which button had been pressed.  It was touch screens before

Answer (score 9):

There were a number of menu builders for DOS such as [MenuWorks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tHY7kM-XN9I) and PowerMenu. [Here](https://books.google.com/books?id=5D4EAAAAMBAJ&lpg=PA39&ots=Kd4IWb0n2I&pg=PA39#v=onepage&q&f=false) is a 1988 article that reviews some others.

Comment: I operated a dial-up BBS back in the early 90s and I recall there were many shareware/freeware “menu” programs too.

Answer (score 5):

I think I know what software you're talking about. I picked up an IBM PC AT off of eBay about a year ago, and the hard drive worked perfectly fine. When I first booted the machine, I was greeted with a text-based menu software, looking like this (I took this photo long after I restored the computer):

[image: Menu software displayed on an IBM PC AT]

After a quick Google search of the company and software, which I have forgotten the name of, all I could find was a Google Books copy of a magazine from the 80's briefly mentioning the release of the software. As far as I know, I'm one of the only people with a copy of the software, named "menu.exe". I hope this is what you were looking for.

Edit: After looking through the magazine linked in snips-n-snails' answer, I found a picture of the software, made by Direct Access.

Comment: @jacobtohan Do you have a website? I want to see more pictures of your lab.

Comment: @snips-n-snails I've actually been working on a website in my spare time and could probably have something up somewhat soon. I have a few more photos and can create an album and link it here tomorrow if you'd like.

Comment: Thank you, but I definitely remember the 3x3 grid being there. I don't think this is it, unless it has different modes.

Comment: @GeorgeT Ah, I've never seen a software like that. Sorry

Comment: This is Direct Access, you can find it here:
https://winworldpc.com/product/direct-access/5x

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like “Deskmate II” or possibly even Saber Menu system.

Deskmate pic from Wikipedia:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Retrocomputing Stack Exchange! Could you elaborate, please? (What does Deskmate II look and behave like? How about Saber? Any additional info that could help the OP decide whether this is it should be [edit]ed into your answer.) Also, you might find the [tour] useful.

Comment: I don't have something I consider suitable to be edited into anyone's answer, but Deskmate 2 and Personal Deskmate 2 can be seen in the Cathode Ray Dude's [Tandy Deskmate Overview](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VuD9i_DMRkk) video.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the first official TUI (Text User Interface) file manager for DOS was [DOS Shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOS_Shell), first distributed as part of MS-DOS and PC DOS v4.0 (1988). Microsoft eventually dropped it from its distributions (though it would still function), probably as a small incentive to MS-DOS users to add an early version of Windows instead.  I believe PC DOS kept it thru its final version (7.x).

(Note that until 1993, with MS-DOS 6.0 and PC DOS 6.1, they were essentially differently-branded versions of the same software. After that, there was still a lot of commonality.  Immediate differences included Microsoft's dropping of DOS Shell, IBM's dropping of QBASIC and adding the superior E editor instead.  (The Microsoft editor had been QBASIC with a different skin.) PC DOS 7 added IBM's own Rexx language to re-offer a programming language to its distribution.)

Comment: Doesn't sound like DOS Shell from the OP's description. DOS Shell either showed a pair of panes (one for the directory tree and one for the files) or a long list of program launch shortcuts. Neither of those views really match up with the 3x3 grid of big boxes.

Comment: I remember DOS Shell. :) It was definitely a different thing.

Comment: Microsoft still provided DOS Shell on later DOS versions, up to MS-DOS 6.22, but it was on the disk of supplements (along with accessibility tools, the BASIC example programs, `EXE2BIN` etc.).

Comment: I guess it depends on your definition of "official," but XTree 1.0 was released in 1985 and offered a full TUI for managing files.  Later versions included a menu-builder for launching applications, but I'm sure it's not what the original poster is describing. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XTree

Comment: IBM had a textmode menu program since DOS 2.0 (fixed disk organizer) from 1984.  When I bought my computer in 1992, it came with a menu from the OEM, being a licenced commercial menu.  It was common practice to load a menu in front of DOS until microsoft changed their licences and said, must boot to DOS or Windows only.

Comment: 'edit' was 'qbasic' with a skin??  I always assumed it was the other way around, that there was 'edit' and they put a 'Run program' option in the menu to make it an "IDE"

Comment: @user1169420 Heh, I guess in one sense it is six of one and a half-dozen of the other.  But I believe my interpretation is slightly more accurate: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MS-DOS_Editor

Answer (score 0):

I used this system!  I can’t remember the name of it, but it was easy to set up and use.  You could even have sub menus with it, like if you set up “G” for games, it could open another menu with the various games which could be accessed with one key.  You could also assign different colors to different menus.  It was really terrific for us DOS users.  I keep thinking of the name “Cheetah,” but that might not be the name of this menu software.

Comment: If you remember more, please [edit] your answer to include it. As it stands, this is just _barely_ an answer, because you've given a potential name. Stack Exchange sites work differently to most forums; see the [tour] and [answer] for more information.

Comment: I added a mockup of how I remember it looking.

Answer (score 0):

I still use an old programm simply called "Hard Disk Menu" (HDM). Perhaps it's this? I think there were newer versions of it, but my one is from 1986.[image]

The third box appears, when you press the '/' key for the configuration.

[image]

Perhaps this is the searched program..?

Thomas

Comment: I added a mockup of how I remember it looking.

Answer (score -1):

I used this software. I want to say it was called Menu Master.

Comment: Welcome to the site Scott! Do you have any links/images you could to this to make the answer a little more useful? I searched for '"Menu master" dos' and two of the images were from this page :)

Comment: There are a number of shareware tools going by the “Menu Master” name, but none of those that I’ve checked look like the mock-up in the question.